# IndexedDB main thread & WebWorker eventlisteners

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, web-worker

Hello I'm building an application in which I use indexeDB. Based on app config I' m able to choose if I should use indexeDB from WebWorker or from the main UI thread. A connection from the main UI thread is always being made regardless of the config. However based on the config the heavy lifting is being done from the worker if selected.

Example of import prototype:

```
Database.prototype.importItem = function(item, callback) {

    if (this.settings.useWorker) {

        this.postMessage({
            cmd: "importItem",
            data: item
        }, callback);

    } else {

        var that = this;
        var transaction = this.db.transaction(this.settings.collection, "readwrite");
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(this.settings.collection);
        var request = objectStore.add(item);

        request.onerror = function(evt) {
            if (callback && callback instanceof Function) {
                callback(new ApplicationError("importItem error", evt.target.error), null);
            }
        };

        request.onsuccess = function(evt) {
            if (callback && callback instanceof Function) {
                callback(null, evt.target.result);
            }
        };

        transaction.oncomplete = function(evt) {};

    }
};
```

What I'm curious about thought is the event listeners that are required from indexedDB, example:

```
Database.prototype.connect = function() {

    if (!this.supported()) {
        return this.emit("error", new ApplicationError("IndexedDB not supported!"));
    }

    var that = this;
    var openRequest = window.indexedDB.open(this.settings.dbName, this.settings.dbVersion);

    /**
     * [onerror description]
     * @param  {[type]} evt [description]
     * @return {[type]}     [description]
     */
    openRequest.onerror = function(evt) {
        that.emit("error", new ApplicationError("openRequest.onerror error", evt.target.error));
    };

    /**
     * [onblocked description]
     * @param  {[type]} evt [description]
     * @return {[type]}     [description]
     */
    openRequest.onblocked = function(evt) {
        // If some other tab is loaded with the database, then it needs to be closed
        // before we can proceed.
        alert("Please close all other tabs with this site open!");
    };

    /**
     * [onsuccess description]
     * @param  {[type]} evt [description]
     * @return {[type]}     [description]
     */
    openRequest.onsuccess = function(evt) {

        that.db = evt.target.result;

        that.db.onerror = function(evt) {
            logger.warn("openRequest.onsuccess error", evt.target);
        };

        that.db.onabort = function(evt) {
            logger.warn("openRequest.onsuccess abort", evt.target);
        };

        that.db.onversionchange = function(evt) {
            that.db.close();
            that.emit("versionchange", new ApplicationError("openRequest.onsuccess version change", evt.target));
        };

        if (that.settings.useWorker) {
            that.requestWorker();
        } else {
            that.emit("connect");
        }

    };

    /**
     * [onupgradeneeded description]
     * @param  {[type]} evt [description]
     * @return {[type]}     [description]
     */
    openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(evt) {

        var stores = {};

        that.db = evt.target.result;

        that.db.onerror = function(evt) {
            logger.warn("openRequest.onupgradeneeded error", evt.target);
        };

        that.db.onabort = function(evt) {
            logger.warn("openRequest.onupgradeneeded abort", evt.target);
        };

        that.db.onversionchange = function(evt) {
            that.db.close();
            that.emit("versionchange", new ApplicationError("openRequest.onupgradeneeded version change", evt.target));
        };

        // Check for the objectStore - collection and delete it if exists
        if (that.db.objectStoreNames.contains(that.settings.collection)) {
            that.db.deleteObjectStore(that.settings.collection);
        }

        // Create new objectStore
        stores[that.settings.collection] = that.db.createObjectStore(that.settings.collection, {
            keyPath: that.settings.indexes[0]
        });

        // Create database indexes
        that.settings.indexes.forEach(function(index) {
            stores[that.settings.collection].createIndex(index, index, {
                unique: false
            });
        });

        that.upgraded = true;
        that.emit("upgrade");

    };

    /**
     * [onbeforeunload description]
     * @param  {[type]} evt [description]
     * @return {[type]}     [description]
     */
    window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
        that.db.close();
    };

};
```

Since I'm connecting always first from the main ui and then from the worker, should I just listen for events like "onblocked, versionchange" only in the main UI thread and not in the worker? I Suppose it wont be needed to listen from both threads?

**UPDATE**

I know that this is a weird implementation but the reason I was thinking about it is because I'm building an app on a very machine that has 3GB of ram and 2 cores... Also I have a method that iterates all records in a collection from my db. What I was thinking is pass each record retrieved to another method for image loading & manipulation and then perhaps call the callback... That would limit the memory usage since it would be done in a serie if I'm not mistaken. However I'm not sure if the transaction will still be alive.

Bottom line that's the main reason I was thinking for 2 connections (because of 1 method) and I was wondering if I could avoid double event listeners. Maybe have some of them on 1 thread.

Comment: Why do you even connect from both threads if you always use the indexedDB from one thread only?

Comment: Because there are methods that are not supported from a webworker. For example I have a method which iterates all items in a collection and passes the cursor to a callback which does canvas drawing, and canvas is not supported in web workers

Comment: Yes, but you don't need indexedDB connection in main thread for that - you can still retrieve the data in Worker and send them to main thread; then draw in canvas. You do NOT need to be connected from both Main thread and the Worker. What you've described is just bad design, or you've described it wrong.

Comment: Yes I suppose that could be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrongly. IndexedDB connection should not be opened on both threads. It makes your app architecture unnecessarily complicated. Data retrieved from IndexedDB can be easily exchanged with UI threads via [Web workers' messaging channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Transferring_data_to_and_from_workers_further_details).

Comment: Yes you are correct I changed my implementaion. however regarding the events onblocked etc are being monitored only in the active thread (worker or main) and messages are being sent to the user

Comment: @Syd I don't get your point.  Could your clarify that? Why will *events onblocked etc are being monitored only in the active thread* be a matter?

Comment: Events are fired at particular object instances (e.g. requests, transactions, connections) which exist only in either a worker or window context and can't be transferred. So if you open a connection in a worker, you can't listen to events from a window since you have nothing to attach the event listener to.

Comment: Well let's assume you have to 2 connections from a worker and from the main thread for some reason.Since you have no way to notify the user directly from the worker about certain events like an alert etc... you have to pass the events back to the main ui. In that case why not listen for those events from the main ui and handle the worker from there close restart it etc etc... Also the original reason I was thinking of using 2 connections was because I have a method which iterates all items in a collection and then pass the cursor to the callaback and call it after some processing.

Comment: In my case the processing would be canvas - image manipulation. So I couldn't in that particular case pass the cursor from a worker to the main thread... Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Syd Why don't you use *messaging channel*? You can still send your records to UI threads, then you can send back the result from UI threads to workers via messaging channel.

Comment: Yea that is what I ended up doing, I redesigned the thing and forgot about passing a cursor